# Cannote generate shim for System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

Here is the error: "Cannot generate shim for System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi: type is now visible to exported or assembly (System.Data.4.0.0.0.Fakes).

Here is my code:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="System.Data" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Remove FullName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <!--Added Classes-->
    <Add FullName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand!"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection!"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataRead"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

In my unit tests I am mocking the SqlDataReader like so:

```
var statReqReader = new ShimSqlDataReader()
        {
            Read = () =>
            {
                if (dsrIndexCounter < testCaseCount)
                {
                    dsrIndexCounter++;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            ItemGetString = (val) =>
            {
                // [] operator
                return dtStatReq.Rows[dsrIndexCounter - 1][val];
            }
        };
```

In general I need to use Fakes in my Unit testing. When I try to remove the following line about the SqlDataReader in the Fakes file

```
<Add FullName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataRead"/>
```

I'm given the following error:

"The type or namespace name 'ShimSqlDataReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I mock the SqlDataReader and need to use Fakes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why? You already have both an interface and an abstract base class that you could use.

Comment: What's a "SqlDataReaderSmi"?

Comment: @JonathanAllen I have updated the question to go into more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Here is what removed the error.

1.I added a sample mock function to see the Shim class of SqlDataReader. Once I found it I realized that I had written the name in the Fakes file specific enough.

2.Replacing the final add with the below line of code fixed the problem.

```
<Add FullName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader!"/>
```